# Solution space of the differential equation $y'' + y =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To  find the dimension  of  the  solution space of  the  equation  given  $y'' +  y = 0$ .

Take $y=e^{mx}$Then  we  have  to  solve  the  equation  $m^{2}+1=0$ for  $m$ . Which  gives  $m=\pm i$. Then  $$y=A e^{ix} + B e^{-ix}$$  [for  arbitrary  real  numbers  $A$  and  $B$] or $$y=(A+B) \cos(x) + i(A-B)\sin(x) $$ or  $$y=D \cos(x)+i C \sin(x)$$
 Its  solution  is  $y= D\cos(x) + i C \sin(x)$  for  $C, D$  arbitrary  real constants.

$$I\ \ do \ \ not\ \ see\ \ why\ \ the \ "i"\ \ should\ \  not \ \  be\ \   there$$

What  is  the  dimension  of  the  solution space  then? Is  it  infinite  because  expanding  $\sin$  and  $\cos$  in  series  we  get all  the  powers  of  $x$ ?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary, what's the point of the $i$ in front?  It's a two-dimensional space because it's the span of two "vectors".

Comment: Maybe he meant "arbitrary real"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : $A$  and $B$  being  arbitrary  constants  ,  only  the  constant  coefficient of  $sin(x)$  needs  to  be  purely  imaginary while   the  other  is  purely  real. That  is  why  the  "$i$"  needs  to  be  there .

Comment: I believe it should *not* be any $i$ in from of $\sin x$, though it does not affect the solution dimension.

Comment: Why do you think that $A$ and $B$ need to be real numbers?

Comment: @A.G. :  If  you  have  the  answer ,  how  about  posting  it  and making   clear if  the  "$i$"  is  important  or  not.

Comment: @user118494 Corrections: a *complex* solution $y=Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}$ for any *complex* constants $A$ and $B$, and then *if* you are interested in *real* solutions only you do rewriting as you did (basically taking $B=\bar A$) and get a real solution $y$ when $D$ and $iC$ are real. Otherwise you are getting complex solutions again, what the point of doing rewriting?

Answer (score 0):

The solution consists of three steps.

1. Show that $A\cos x+B\sin x$ *is* a solution (a simple substitution).
2. Show that *any* real solution $y$ has the form $y=A\cos x+B\sin x$. Indeed, 
   $$
   z=y-A\cos x-B\sin x
   $$
   is a solution too by linearity. Moreover, $z(0)=y(0)-A$ and $z'(0)=y'(0)-B$, so taking $A=y(0)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $B=y'(0)\in\mathbb{R}$ we get the solution $z$ with the zero initial condition. By uniqueness, $z\equiv 0$ and then
   $$
   y(x)=y(0)\cos x+y'(0)\sin x.
   $$
3. Show that the solution subspace $L=\{A\cos x+B\sin x\}$ has dimension $2$, since $L\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ by the bijection 
   $$
   L\ni y=A\cos x+B\sin x\quad\sim\quad\left[\matrix{A\\B}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^2.
   $$

P.S. The (real) dimension of $\{D\cos x+iC\sin x\colon \ C,D\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is also $2$ as $\mathbb{R}\cong i\mathbb{R}$, but it is no clear why you pick just those complex solutions from the set of all complex solutions.